# Help with computing Galois group of $x^4 - 3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $f(x) = x^4 - 3$. I believe $Gal(f(x)) = Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}, i)/\mathbb{Q})$, and then we have

$$\sigma_1 = 
          \begin{cases}
          \sqrt[4]{3} \rightarrow \zeta^n\sqrt[4]{3}, n = 0,1,2,3\\
          i \rightarrow i
          \end{cases},$$

and complex conjugation as another automorphism. Then our group is of order 8? How do I determine where $\sigma_1$ takes $\zeta$? And does that help me determine the group? I'm not sure how to handle it from here.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\zeta=i$ or what?

Answer (score 7):

Well note that first we need to extend into $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ so that we write
$$
x^4-3 = (x^2 - \sqrt{3})(x^2 + \sqrt{3})
$$
and then we need to extend into $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[4]{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})$ since
$$
(x^2 - \sqrt{3})(x^2 + \sqrt{3}) = (x - \sqrt[4]{3})(x + \sqrt[4]{3})(x^2 + \sqrt{3})
$$
Now if for the sake of seeing where to extend to next, let's work in $\mathbb{C}$ and use the quadratic formula to find the linear factors of $x^2 + \sqrt{3}$:
$$
x_0 = \frac{\pm\sqrt{-4\sqrt{3}}}{2} = \pm i \sqrt[4]{3}
$$
so clearly we need to extend into $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i)$.

Now note that this is a separable polynomial (since in it's splitting field there are no repeated roots). This tells us that, denoting $E$ the extension field and $F$ the base field we have
$$
\left| \mathrm{Gal}(E/F) \right| = [E : F]
$$
Since for this polynomial $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i), F = \mathbb{Q}$ and we have
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 4, [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i) : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3})] = 2 \implies [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i) : \mathbb{Q}] = 8
$$
Now an explanation for these above equalities would be needed for a valid proof, I'll leave that to you, but a hint would be to think of the minimal polynomials of the elements that are being adjoined.

So now we know that the size of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{3},i) / \mathbb{Q})$ is $8$.

Now for the automorphisms, note that $i \to \pm i$ so you automatically have two automorphisms. Now we have that $\sqrt[4]{3}$ can be sent to any other fourth root of $3$. So since there are four choices for our roots, and two choices for $i$ we have our $8$ automorphisms. Note that defining the automorphisms for just $i$ and $\sqrt[4]{3}$ are sufficient for defining the entire automorphisms (why?). These automorphisms are as follow:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to 3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to i3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to -3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to -i3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to i \end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to 3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to -i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to i3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to -i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to -3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to -i \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 3^{1 / 4} \to -i3^{1 / 4} \\ i \to -i \end{pmatrix} \\
$$

I hope this helps you understand how to determine the group. I usually find the size of the group to see how many elements I need to look for. Next I would think about where the adjoined elements can go. From there we can create any possible automorphism.

Also another comment: If you put $s = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt[4]{3} \to i\sqrt[4]{3} \\ i \to -i \end{pmatrix}, r = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt[4]{3} \to i\sqrt[4]{3} \\ i \to i \end{pmatrix}$ we see that this group is isomorphic to $D_4$!

Comment: Thanks so much, but at the end do you mean that $s$ sends $\sqrt[4]{3}$ to itself and $i$ to $-i$?

Comment: @user121937 it's possible that $s$ can be that isomorphism, but this one works too. I derived mine by imaging the roots on a graph and then creating a square out of them and applying the transformations of $s$ and $r$ to see where each root goes.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. If this were something of a larger degree and I suspected it was $D_8,$ say, would the best course of action be to see how what some automorphisms do to two adjacent roots? And if the automorphisms always send them to adjacent spots again then I know it is rigid motion?

Comment: @user121937 well just because you know that adjacent roots can be sent to each other doesn't mean that the automorphism group is in fact some dihedral group. We know that for a polynomial $f$ where $\partial(f) = n$ we have $\mathrm{Gal}(f) \subset S_n$. There are in fact polynomials that have galois group equal to $S_n$. This would look like a dihedral group at first, since adjacent roots permute, but there would also be extra members. Note however in that case the symmetric group would be strictly larger so finding out the size of the group really is very helpful in general.